# Spring Data Jpa / Hades Transaction Behaviour

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, dao, spring-data

From [Spring Data JPA reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions) (previously [Hades](http://hades.synyx.org)),

> CRUD methods on repository instances
>   are transactional by default.

If a method covers more than one repository, example:

```
@Transactional
public void addRoleToAllUsers(String roleName) {
    Role role = roleRepository.findByName(roleName);
    for (User user : userRepository.readAll()) {
        user.addRole(role);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

The reference states

> The transaction configuration at the
>   repositories will be neglected then as
>   the outer transaction configuration
>   determines the actual one used.

The behavior **inner transactions will be neglected** is a default spring transaction behavior or actually explicitly handled by Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a default behaviour.

As you can see, methods of [`JpaRepository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) are annotated as `@Transactional` with propagation by default (`REQUIRED`), and it's a normal behaviour for that propagation type (see [10.5.7 Transaction propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation)).

Comment: The reference states "transactions will be neglected" seems to be misleading.

Comment: @CK: Sound oversimplified, but clear for me - `@Transactional` at repository methods doesn't cause transactions to be created when called inside another transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transactional` at the `JpaRepository`/the implementation class will cause these methods simply taking part in the outer transaction by default. So if you think "neglect" is a misleading word feel free to open a JIRA for it (I think it is to some degree ;) ).

If you want to change the configuration of transactions for the CRUD methods you can do so by simply redeclaring the CRUD method inside your concrete repository interface and add an `@Transactional` to it containing the config you want to have. See the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the propagation set in the @Transactional annotation. By default, it's set to `REQUIRED`, which means : if no transaction context, create one and commit at the end of the method; else, include the method call inside the existing transaction context.

There are other ones : REQUIRES_NEW, SUPPORTS, NEVER, etc. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html for details.